# Referencing struct definition inside class in CRTP

Tags: c++, struct, crtp, incomplete-type

I'm using static polymorphism (CRTP method) to create class hierarchy. The idea is to use a struct defined in derived class in base one. However, VC10 generates following error:

`error C2039: 'param_t' : is not a member of 'D'`

and Intel C++ generates following error:

`error : incomplete type is not allowed`

It's quite confusing that `Derived::param_t` is a `struct` type and shall be compiled normally. Please point out the problem in the code. Thanks.

```
// Base class
template<typename Derived>
struct Base {
  typedef typename Derived::param_t param_t; //error c2039

  void setParam(param_t& param);
  const param_t& getParam() const;
  ...

};

// Derived class
class D: public Base<D> {
public:
  struct param_t {
    double a, b, c;
  };

  D(param_t& param):param_(param) {}
  ...

protected:
  param_t param_;   

};

int main()
{
  D::param_t p = {1.0, 0.2, 0.0};
  D *pD = new D(p);
}
```

Comment: Can you show all references to `param_t` in `Base`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ static polymorphism (CRTP) and using typedefs from derived classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006614/c-static-polymorphism-crtp-and-using-typedefs-from-derived-classes)

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), in particular on how to research your questions before posting them. E.g. searching for "CRTP incomplete type" would have given you plenty of information.

Comment: Sorry for posting duplicate topic. The solution is a trait class or a template member function 'setParam' 'getParam'. I prefer latter, because the 'struct' definition shall be inside 'class D' for encapsulation purpose. Thanks for all help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use types from derived class in base class definition. You can use it only inside bodies of member functions. The problem is that `typedef typename Derived::param_t param_t` is resolved for `class D: public Base<D>` when compiler doesn't know yet about nested types of D. Member functions are compiled after actual instantiation of D when definition of D is available.

I think in your case you can't use CRTP method.

Comment: I see, this is a circular referencing scheme. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. Definitions of both classes depends from each other.