# Using typedefs of a non-template derived class in the base class when using CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I'm using CRT pattern and want the base class to see `typedef`s from the derived class. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006614/c-static-polymorphism-crtp-and-using-typedefs-from-derived-classes)  @James McNellis suggested to do that using `base_traits` class and it works fine. But in the case described in that post the derived class itself is a template. This approach does not work in VS2010 when the derived class is not a template.

```
template <class D>
struct base_traits;
template <class D>
struct base
{
    typedef typename base_traits<D>::value_t value_t;
};

struct derived : base<derived>
{
    typedef typename base_traits<derived>::value_t value_t;
};

template<>
struct base_traits<derived>
{
    typedef int value_t;
};
```

The above code gives lots of errors. The first one is:

> error C2027: use of undefined type 'base_traits

on the line of the `base` class's typedef.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`base_traits<derived>` must be declared and defined prior it's usage since it is needed for the implicit instancation of `base<derived>` (below, I forward declared `derived`) :

```
template <class D>
struct base_traits;


template <class D>
struct base
{
    typedef typename base_traits<D>::value_t value_t;
};

struct derived;

template<>
struct base_traits<derived>
{
    typedef int value_t;
};

struct derived : base<derived>
{
    typedef base_traits<derived>::value_t value_t;
};


int main(void)
{
    derived d;
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e3427f2ef9ff643)

Comment: Generally the definition of the base and declaration of the base_traits classes should go to one header and the definition of the derived and its base_traits specialization to another header, and the second header should include the first one, so having base_traits specialization for the derived class defined before the base class is practically not usable.

Comment: @MihranHovsepyan indeed, the above order is now equivalent to `base_traits` , `base` in one header, and the `base_traits<>` specialization + `derived` in another. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see, the above answer is written in that way. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

§14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec]/p7:

> The placement of explicit specialization declarations for function
>   templates, class templates, variable templates, member functions of
>   class templates, static data members of class templates, member
>   classes of class templates, member enumerations of class templates,
>   member class templates of class templates, member function templates
>   of class templates, static data member templates of class templates,
>   member functions of member templates of class templates, member
>   functions of member templates of non-template classes, static data
>   member templates of non-template classes, member function templates of
>   member classes of class templates, etc., and the placement of partial
>   specialization declarations of class templates, variable templates,
>   member class templates of non-template classes, static data member
>   templates of non-template classes, member class templates of class
>   templates, etc., can affect whether a program is well-formed according
>   to the relative positioning of the explicit specialization
>   declarations and their points of instantiation in the translation unit
>   as specified above and below. **When writing a specialization, be
>   careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial
>   as to kindle its self-immolation.**

In particular (§14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec]/p6),

> If a template [...] is explicitly specialized then that specialization
>   shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that
>   would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every
>   translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is
>   required. If the program does not provide a definition for an
>   explicit specialization and [...] the specialization is used in a way
>   that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place [...], 
>   the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

The explicit specialization `base_traits<derived>` must be declared and defined before the definition of `derived`, as otherwise both inheriting from `base<derived>` and using `base_traits<derived>::value_t` would trigger an implicit instantiation. Thus:

```
template <class D>
struct base_traits;

template <class D>
struct base
{
    typedef typename base_traits<D>::value_t value_t;
};

struct derived;

template<>
struct base_traits<derived>
{
    typedef int value_t;
};

struct derived : base<derived>
{
    typedef base_traits<derived>::value_t value_t;
};
```

Comment: I'll admit that the only reason I posted this answer is because I get to quote §14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec]/p7 :)

Comment: +1 for quoting (and highlighting!) my favourite sentence in the standard :-)