# CRTP: function with derived-based argument

Tags: c++, crtp

Here's a minimal version of what I'm trying to do:

```
template<typename D>
struct Base {

        void common() {
                // ... do something ...
                static_cast<D *>(this)->impl();
                // ... do something ...
        }

        void common_with_arg(typename D::Arg arg) {
                // ... do something ...
                static_cast<D *>(this)->impl_with_arg(arg);
                // ... do something more ...
        }
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived> {
        void impl() { }

        using Arg = int;
        void impl_with_arg(Arg arg) { }

};
```

`Base::common()` and `Derived::impl()` work OK (as expected).
`Base::common_with_arg()` and `Derived::impl_with_arg()`, however, do not.

With gcc, for example, I get the following error:

```
1.cc: In instantiation of ‘struct Base<Derived>’:
1.cc:18:18:   required from here
1.cc:11:7: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Derived’
  void common_with_arg(typename D::Arg arg) {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1.cc:18:8: note: forward declaration of ‘struct Derived’
 struct Derived : Base<Derived> {
```

Intuitively (without understanding all details about template instantiation), this seems like a sensible error. Is there another way to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void common_with_arg(typename D::Arg arg)
//                            ^^^^^^
```

You cannot access `D::Arg` here, as the definition of `Derived` would be required. But the definition is never available as the `Base` template is being instantiated here...

```
struct Derived : Base<Derived> { 
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...where `Derived` is not yet fully-defined.

---

One possible workaround is making `common_with_arg` a function template:

```
template <typename T>
void common_with_arg(T&& arg) {
        // ... do something ...
        static_cast<D *>(this)->impl_with_arg(std::forward<T>(arg));
        // ... do something more ...
}
```

[**example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rGINnnu0utKWAqlY)

---

If you really need the `Arg` type alias, read this question:
 [**"C++ static polymorphism (CRTP) and using typedefs from derived classes"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006614/c-static-polymorphism-crtp-and-using-typedefs-from-derived-classes).

Comment: Thanks! I came up with a similar solution a few minutes after writing the question, but yours is better since  I used `(T arg)` instead of `(T&& arg)`.

Comment: I'd rather suggest `template<typename T = D> void common_with_arg(typename T::Arg&& arg) { static_cast<T *>(this)->impl_with_arg(std::forward<Arg>(arg)); } `. So that `arg` is constrained to type `D::Arg` as shown in the example code. cc @ynimous