# c++ static polymorphism (CRTP) Resulting in incomplete type when evaluating a `static constexpr`

Tags: c++, visual-c++, metaprogramming, crtp, static-polymorphism

I need access to a `static constexpr` and one solution I put together works with gcc ([live example](https://rextester.com/ZPN24687)) but not with vc++ ([live example](https://rextester.com/FNQJ44727)).

The code is as follows:

```
template<class Drvd>
class Base
{
public:
    static constexpr bool val = Drvd::val;
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    friend class Base;
private:
    static constexpr bool val = true;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Derived::Base::val << std::endl;
}
```

So it is a bug with vc++, but anyone has an idea on how to achieve `val` defined in `Base` as the value of `val` in `Drvd` in a different way that vc++ won't complain about?

**Edit:**
Note that the result is the same with the variant: `friend class Base<Derived>;` instead of `friend class Base;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ static polymorphism (CRTP) and using typedefs from derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006614/c-static-polymorphism-crtp-and-using-typedefs-from-derived-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @David, the problem has to do with `Face` being incomplete, because it goes into `Base` before finishing the definition of `Face`.

However, the solution linked to by @David is a bit old and misses some tricks of which we can take advantage. Namely, @m.s. shows us that `static constexpr` functions are fine - and also based on my own experimentation - and we really only need to deal with this particular case of `static constexpr` variables, and perhaps types accessed from `Derived`.

The following ([live example](https://rextester.com/OLSH94313)) shows how to solve this problem, while keeping each class encapsulated to it's own h-file, making it somewhat cleaner:

```
#include <iostream>

// Begin: h-file of Base
template<class Drvd>
class ConstValue;

template<class Drvd>
class Base
{
public:
    static constexpr bool val = ConstValue<Drvd>::val;
};
// End: h-file of Base

// Begin: h-file of Derived
class Derived;

template<>
class ConstValue<Derived>
{
public:
    static constexpr bool val = true;
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    friend class Base<Derived>;
private:
    static constexpr bool val = true; // optional
};
// End: h-file of Derived

// Main
int main()
{
    std::cout << Derived::Base::val << std::endl;
}
```

The general idea is that for each `constexpr` that `Base` needs to access from `Derived`, we can create a single class that encapsulate the variables, and then overload the class for each `Derived` that uses `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a method:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Drvd>
class Base
{
public:
    static constexpr bool val() { return Drvd::val;  }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    friend class Base<Derived>;
private:
    static constexpr bool val = true;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Derived::Base::val() << std::endl;
}
```

live example: https://rextester.com/IHR24393

Comment: Nice variant, but I would have to resort to adding `()`. If nothing else, I guess this would have to do. Thanks.

Comment: One other comment, using a `constexpr` function, while working for this particular case, is also limiting in being able to use `val()` as a template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is not the private/friend declarations (the code wouldn't compile even if 
"val" was a public), your problem is that during instantiation of

```
static constexpr bool val = Drvd::val
```

Drvd is still incomplete type. 
See below question/answer on how to workaround this with traits classes.

[C++ static polymorphism (CRTP) and using typedefs from derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006614/c-static-polymorphism-crtp-and-using-typedefs-from-derived-classes])

P.S. in fact I just flagged your question as duplicate

Comment: thanks, this seems to be the right direction. Although I'm not sure if it's directly a duplicate, but I will try to play around with the information on the other page and see what results.