# g++ thinks my class declaration is a "forward declaration"

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, crtp

Stripped down to the bare minimum, here's the code I'm trying to compile:

```
template<class T>
class B
{
  protected:

    std::vector<typename T::I> v;

  public:

    template<class... Args>
    void add(Args... args )
    {
      this->v.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    typename T::I get(int i)
    {
      return this->v[i];
    }
};

class D : public B<D>
{
  public:

    typedef std::string I;
};
```

If I instantiate `D` and try to compile this in `g++`, it complains:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class D’
>
> ```
> std::vector<typename T::I> v;
> ```

and adds a note,

> note: forward declaration of ‘class D’
>
> ```
> class D : public B<D>
> ```

If I try `clang++` instead, I get a different error:

> error: no type named 'I' in 'D'
>
> ```
> std::vector<typename T::I> v;
> ```

I'm sure I'm just doing something silly here but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: At the point `std::vector<typename T::I>` `T` is incomplete. The compiler is right.

Comment: I dimly remember I used this style a few years ago (maybe 10 years). Back then, it worked for me (on the then current MSVC compiler). Recently I tried something like that, as well and I ran into some problems. I attributed that to me being rusty :)

Comment: MSVC is notorious for letting weird things fly with templates.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [C++ static polymorphism (CRTP) and using typedefs from derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6006614/27678)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is just that when you write

```
class D : public B<D>
```

you pass the class `D` as template parameter of `B` when `D` is still incomplete.

So the compiler can't see `D::I` because isn't defined at this point.

g++ explicitly say this: "error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class D’".

clang++ dosn't say this explicitly but doesn't find `I` for this reason.

**-- EDIT --**

The OP asks

> How do you do what I want to do, then?

The only solution that I see (not a great solution, unfortunately) is define what you need in `B` in another class/struct, say `C`

```
struct C
 { using I = std::string; };
```

and inherit `D` from `C` and `B<C>`

```
class D : public C, public B<C>
 { };
```

This way `C` is fully defined, when you use it as template parameter for `B`, and also inherited from `D`.

Comment: How do you do what I want to do, then?

Comment: Use a different language. What you want to do isn't valid C++.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Maybe give `B` an additional template argument and have it provide an alias to it as `I`. So instead of having `D` have an alias for `std::string`, give `std::string` as a template argument and get `B` to provide `I` instead.

Comment: @Blindy: Now that's not very productive :/

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - my fault: I've done some confusion between `B` and `D`.