# Is it legal to use struct itself as template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, language-lawyer, incomplete-type

According to [Template parameters and template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) on cppreference.com:

> A template argument for a type template parameter must be a type-id,
> which **may name an incomplete type**

That means that this example (copied from that page) is legal:

```
// Example 0

template <typename T>
struct X {};

struct A;

int main() {
    X<A> x1;
}
```

and, I suppose, also this is legal:

```
// Example 1

template <typename T>
struct X {};

struct A {
    X<A> x1;
};

int main() {
    A a1;
}
```

Now, let's complicate a bit the code:

```
// Example 2

template <typename T>
struct X {
    using type = typename T::type;
};

struct A {
    using type = int;
    X<A>::type x1;
};

int main() {
    A a1;
}
```

In this case, `A` is still an incomplete type when used as template argument, and the code compiles. Now, if I change the order of the lines in `A`:

```
// Example 3

template <typename T>
struct X {
    using type = typename T::type;
};

struct A {
    X<A>::type x1; // ERROR HERE
    using type = int;
};

int main() {
    A a1;
}
```

the code does not compile anymore. Clang error message is something like `no type named 'type' in 'A'`, but also GCC, ICC and MSVC return similar errors (see [this demo on godbolt.com](https://godbolt.org/z/nWxosxcYG)), and this seems almost identical to that of typedefs on CRTP, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006614/c-static-polymorphism-crtp-and-using-typedefs-from-derived-classes).

Anyway, the behavior seems reasonable: compilers use all the properties of `A` defined at the point `X<A>` is used.

But what does the C++14 (or later) standard say about it? Is it legal to rely on the behavior of the working **Example 2**?

Comment: Replace the ERROR HERE line with `typename X<A>::type x1;`

Comment: This has nothing to do with templates. Try the same thing with inline functions. You will see the exact same behavior. Or macros that references a function like absl mutex macros.

Comment: @Eljay That line is not in a templated entity. `typename` is not required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [CWG issue 287](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#287).

You can look at the reasoning there, but my understanding from it is that the consensus is that the standard technically currently doesn't allow either your last or second-to-last example, since the point of instantiation of `X<A>` will be before the definition of `A`, where `typename T::type` cannot be formed.

However, as indicated in the proposed resolution, it is intended that even though the point of instantiation would be before the definition of `A`, names declared in `A` before the point requiring instantiation of `X<A>` shall still be visible to the instantiation.

That is what the compilers implement and you observe.