# Is there a way for a CRTP base class to access types in derived class?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I'm trying to access a derived class type from inside a CRTP base, such as:

```
template <typename CRTP>
class Base {
   using Type = typename CRTP::Type;

   void method(const Type& t) {
      do_something();
      static_cast<CRTP&>(*this).derived_method( t );
   }

   void do_something() {
   }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
   using Type = int;

   void derived_method(const Type& t ) {
   }
};
```

which doesn't work because CRTP is incomplete in the declaration of Base.  I understand the error.  Is there a reasonable workaround to get a similar effect?

I see a similar question at [C++ static polymorphism (CRTP) and using typedefs from derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006614/c-static-polymorphism-crtp-and-using-typedefs-from-derived-classes), but that solution doesn't work in my case.  For that question, the base class was looking for a template parameter of Derived, not an internal type, so a traits class was able to get at the type without looking inside the declaration of Derived.

Everything I can come up with involves repeating the definition of `Derived::Type = int` in one way or another instead of using what's already in Derived.

Comment: For my immediate problem, it will be the argument type of a method in Base.  I'm not sure if I'll have other needs for it, so the more general the solution, the better.

Comment: You cannot do it within class declaration. But you can do it inside the function definition.

Comment: Change `template <typename CRTP>` to `template <typename CRTP, typename Type>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you need, but it'll delay the use of the `CRTP` class until it's complete:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename CRTP>
class Base {
public:
    void method(const auto& t) {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>,
                                     typename CRTP::Type>);

        do_something();
        static_cast<CRTP&>(*this).derived_method(t);
    }

    void do_something() {
    }
};
```